# why IEnumerable<T> needs to implement IEnumerable

Tags: c#, oop

If I just want to use the generic version IEnumerable, I have to implement not only `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()` but also `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()`, the latter seems to be redundant

Comment: I found the duplicate by searching in google for `why IEnumerable<T> needs to implement IEnumerable`

Answer (score 1):

[`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netframework-4.8) interface was introduced in 1.1 .net framework.
But generic version [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8) in 2.0 only (with generics). So, it's backward compatibility. There is legacy code, that accept only `IEnumerable`:

```
void Method(IEnumerable list)
{
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

So if `IEnumerable<T>` does not implement `IEnumerable`, you can not pass `List<int>` in this method, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are two reasons:

- compatibility. A lot of legacy code, which can deal with `IEnumerable`, but can't deal with `IEnumerable<T>`. Yes, modern APIs are being designed to use generics, but from time to time we need to use legacy APIs.
- there are cases, when you want to enumerate, but don't care at design-time about object type or boxing. `IEnumerable` is OK here. Data binding is the most obvious one.